# "Declining because... other..." field is broken in Iceweasel/Firefox

Tags: bug, status-completed, moderator-tools, flags, firefox

To reproduce:

- Hit the *Decline* button on a flag
- Select *Other...* as the reason
- Click inside the text field

Focus will be immediately moved to the *Other...* radio button, making it impossible to type in the text field.

Note that after selecting *Other...*, focus is initially moved to the text field. It's only after re-clicking the text field that focus is moved away.

I experienced this problem in Iceweasel 12.0 on Debian Linux 6.0.2.  Chromium 6.0.472.63 did not exhibit the same behavior.

[image]

Comment: I can comfirm the problem in FireFox.  WTH is Iceweasel? :P

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Iceweasel is Debian's rebranded-for-legal-reasons Firefox.

Comment: *Iceweasel* <--- I see what they did there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build (after rev 2012.5.30.2722).